# How to move to the directory with the latest date of change?

Tags: bash, cd

I write  the script which will kill tomcat's process, clean some directories and move files from newest folder in directory '~/Cats' to сleaned directory .

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -9 -f tomcat
cd ~/mishka/prod
rm -r webapps/*
cd ~/mishka/prod
?????????????
cp file ~/mishka/prod/webapps
bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems using a Question/Answer format. Your posting doesn't have any code that we can help you fix and the connection between the Subject line c and the text in your post is unclear. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, why is my question not traditional?   I add some bash-code, but I don't understand how it can help with question. This is the third my Q. What's wrong?

Comment: Glad you added some code, and please reread my comment above. I rephrased my comment to help you understand why you don't have a good question. Even with your code, I'm still not clear what you're trying to accomplish and it would be good if you added some explanatory text to the body of your Q to help readers understand where you are having trouble. Again, read the links provided to understand how to write a good Q for stackOverflow. Good luck.

Comment: Just to understand correctly, is this the question: If given a directory, how do I find the subdirectory which has most recently been modified?

Comment: Searching here for `[bash] newest file` shows 250+ Q/A that you can read. Good luck.

Comment: shelter, I wanted information about newest directory. Not file.

Comment: yes, `[bash] newest directory` returns ~150 QA. Please learn to search before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to find the newest stuff.

All you have to do is

```
cd ~/Cats
tmp=`ls -1tr | tail -1`
cd $tmp
```

Now you can copy the files from there or move them somewhere else.

Thanks